# jQuery multiple dynamically created slide down DIV's all open at once

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, jquery-ui-accordion, slidedown

I have some slide down boxes that are being created dynamically as shown in the PHP snippet below. At the moment when you click the title to drop down it opens every div as you can see in the fiddle below. How do I add the variable from PHP and work it into the jQuery script so that each title open its on own div without affecting others? In effect what i'm looking for is an accordion function with PHP vars.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amesy/tkp3jzrp/)

JQUERY

```
$(function(){

//category drop downs

$(".category").hide();
$( ".tags h5" ).addClass( "open" );

var cat_open = 0;

$(".tags h5").click(function () {

    if (cat_open == 1) {
        $(".category").animate({"height":"toggle"}, 500);
        cat_open = 0;
        $( ".tags h5" ).addClass( "open" );
    }
    else if (cat_open == 0) {
        $(".category").animate({"height":"toggle"}, 500);
        cat_open = 1;
        $( ".tags h5" ).removeClass( "open" );
    }

});
});
```

PHP

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ){

echo '<h5 class="">'. $category->name . '</h5>';

echo'<div class="category '. $category->name . '">';

$sub_args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'tags',
    'parent'        => $category->term_id, // get child categories
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hierarchical'  => 1,
    'pad_counts'    => 0
);

$sub_categories = get_categories( $sub_args );

foreach ( $sub_categories as $sub_category ){

    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" id="type-'. $sub_category->name . '" rel="'. $sub_category->name . '">'. $sub_category->name . '</label>';

    echo '<br />';

}

echo'</div>';//.categories

echo '<hr />';

}
```

Comment: why are you adding "open" class to the h5's ? Also post the rest of your structure. Is there an h5 and a .category next to it each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use open classes (in this case), you just need to use

```
$(".tags h5").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".category").slideToggle();
});
```

[**See working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ge1xuefj/)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without php. 
http://jsfiddle.net/tkp3jzrp/2/

```
$(function(){

    //category drop downs

    $(".category").hide();
    $( ".tags h5" ).addClass( "open" );

    $(".tags h5").click(function () {           
          $(this).next('.category').animate({"height":"toggle"}, 500);           

    });
});
```